# Cannot publish WebMatrix website

Tags: webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I figured I would play around with WebMatrix today and it fails during publishing. I'm receiving this error message:

> "ERROR: Make sure you have appropriate permissions on the server to
>   publish IIS settings. Alternatively, exclude settings that require
>   administrative permission on the server."

I'm not sure why the application would be trying to modify any settings within IIS. The only actual code I have on the site is a select query.

I couldn't find any information on this error message and I'm not sure what else to check. I made sure that I had the settings on my shared hosting set to .NET 4.0 (Integrated)

Any help would why this if failing and a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called my hosting provider after an hour or so of trying to figure out what could possibly be wrong. Turned out the issue was on their end. They upgraded the servers Web Deploy version and fixed some delegation settings.